# Android simple parse parameter to AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to simply send pass integer to `AsyncTask` . in `doInBackground` i can not get correctly that. for example:

```
new LongOperation().execute ( 20 );
```

i get this Result :

```
1266-2259/com.sample E/AsyncTask ------------------﹕ [Ljava.lang.Integer;@418e6bd0
```

My code:

```
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try {
            Log.e("AsyncTask ------------------ ", params+"");
            getFromServerAndUpdateDB ( params );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        updateDialog();
        notification ();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Comment: params[0] holds your value.

Comment: what is getFromServerAndUpdateDB doing and where are you actualy getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

params... is an array. Try:

```
Log.e("AsyncTask ------------------ ", params[0] +"");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're using something called "varargs" when you get your integer `params`, as indicated by the three dots after the type. This means that params is an array of strings. To get the first one, you need to access it like you would any other array: `params[0]`.

Edit: Here's the Oracle page about varargs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 0):

Params is an Integer array, so first you need to get the first index of that array.

Also, you pass in a String into the Log statement, so you also need to convert the Integer to a String:

```
Log.e("AsyncTask ------------------ ", Integer.toString(params[0])+"");
```

That should work just fine.